# Android Main activity listening and receiving values/signals from another activity periodically

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a **MainActivity.java** that implementing AlarmManager which to listening to **SecondActivity.java** periodically and trying to get the ongoing value from **SecondActivity.java**. Can anyone please give me some advice on achieving this?

Comment: It's hard to tell! How can two activities be running at the same time with one listening to the other? Can you please explain your problem better? Check IntentServices, bound services, BroadcastReceivers, asynctasks to better understand your needs. You can also use a static singleton object...it depends on what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is running in MainActivity needs to be moved to a service or something that has a lifecycle independant of which is currently displayed on the screen.
This is because Activities can be killed off by the OS while they are not in focus.

I would suggest an IntentService that when it runs it does the periodic task you need then schedules itself to run again via a pending intent.

A good example of this is here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html